# Rank based on multiple columns without helper columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Currently have Ranking by multiple columns but I want to do this without having helper columns (Points). Need a formula that will combine the following functions into one. Using Excel with Office365 by the way with all the new functions available.

- Vlookup Points based on Actual % of Apples
- Vlookup Points based on Actual % of Oranges
- Combine both results and rank against other rows without creating helper columns.

[image]

[Excel Online File](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aq9G2vFp7ggQjgHHd1U1by7SmMr1?e=rY4ajn)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use helper table then you have to hard code percentage and points inside function. As you are using `M365`, I will advise to use `XLOOKUP()` and declare percentage and points as array inside xlookup-

For apple ranking, use-

```
=XLOOKUP(B5,{0,0.8,0.85,0.9,0.95,1,1.05,1.1,1.15,1.2,1.25,1.3,1.35,1.4},{0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,5.5,6,6.5},"",-1)
```

For orange ranking, use-

```
=XLOOKUP(D5,{0,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3,0.35,0.4},{0,0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5,3},0,-1)
```

**Note: Percentages are cell format (in cell it has actual numerical value), so use actual values of percent inside formula.**

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, and not mistaken then you are asking to use an **`Excel Formula`** which will perform the lookup up on the actual percentages of both apples and oranges as well as output the rank based on the sum of the points.

And since there is no **`Excel Constraints`** then one of the following formula can be used to return a spill i.e. one single dynamic array formula for the whole range. That said, the formulas you can use are:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F5</kbd> using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, VLOOKUP(B5:B14,H6:I19,2)+VLOOKUP(D5:D14,K6:L12,2),
     MMULT(N(α<TOROW(α)),TOCOL(α)^0)+1)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F5</kbd> using <kbd>LAMBDA( )</kbd> helper function <kbd>MAP( )</kbd>

```
=LET(
     φ, VLOOKUP(B5:B14,H6:I19,2)+VLOOKUP(D5:D14,K6:L12,2),
     MAP(φ,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(φ>x))+1)))
```

---

**Note:** Your posted screenshot has a typo, if i am not wrong, if i am then please correct me, the rows 7, 11 & 14 rankings, the following screenshot explains the error.

[image]

---

Comment: You're right about the error. In Row 7 for Rep 3, I used following formula which may be causing the error. "=RANK.EQ($C7, $C$5:$C$14) + COUNTIFS($C$5:$C$14, $C7, $E$5:$E$14, ">" &$E7)". Going to review your formula and mark as Accept once it works. Thank you.